# runtime loading of ValidateAntiForgeryToken Salt value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf, salt

Consider an ASP.NET MVC application using the `Salt` parameter in the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` directive.

The scenario is such that the app will be used by many customers. It's not terribly desirable to have the `Salt` known at compile time.

The current strategy is to locate the Salt value in the web.config.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Config.AppSalt)]
//Config.AppSalt is a static property that reads the web.config.
```

This leads to a compile-time exception suggesting that the `Salt` must be a const at compile time.

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

How can I modify the application to allow for a runtime loading of the `Salt` so that the app doesn't have to be re-salted and recompiled for each customer?

Consider that the `Salt` won't change frequently, if at all, thereby removing the possibility of invalidating form

Comment: As Levi the Microsoft MVC security guys states, you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the requirement to have different salts for different customers. In this case, I used Dixin's solution for injecting the salt at runtime.

[Anti Forgery Request Recipes For ASP.NET MVC and AJAX](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx) at the section titled "**Specify non-constant salt in runtime**".

Decorate your Controllers with a new attribute:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenWrapper(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public class ProductController : Controller
{     
    // Only HTTP POST requests are validated.
}
```

This new attribute is defined as:

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenWrapperAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public ValidateAntiForgeryTokenWrapperAttribute(HttpVerbs verbs)
    {
        this._verbs = new AcceptVerbsAttribute(verbs);
        this._validator = new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
            {
                //load from web.config or anywhere else
                Salt = Configurations.AntiForgeryTokenSalt
            };
    }

    // Other members.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Salt property is meant to be a compile-time constant.  It's simply a way to link a particular form to a particular action method.  For example, if you have a login form, you may wish to use the salt "Login" for this form so that a token that was valid for the login form can't be used for the change password form, etc.

In all cases, the app's machine key is automatically used as an *additional* salt value.  So an anti-XSRF token for one application can't be used for another application, even if both salt values read "Login".  The machine key is settable in the Web.config [<machineKey>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) section.

Comment: If I have a login form I don't need anti-forgery protection at all, do I? Because user is not yet authenticated and there is nothing yet to protect from.

Comment: If you do not protect the login form, you are potentially open to Login CSRF.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF#Forging_login_requests for more information.

(Edit: the 'Salt' property has been removed from MVC 4 since most applications do not need it. See docs for more info if you were using it.)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. But according to the article it's possible only in context of Flash (crossdomain.xml), regular sites aren't affected?

Comment: Login CSRF doesn't require Flash.  Including a crossdomain.xml file will prevent Flash-based exploits (which is why it is under the 'Countermeasures' heading), but an attacker can still perform regular CSRF (and login CSRF) attacks using ordinary Javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. CSRF is "a type of malicious exploit of a website whereby unauthorized commands are transmitted from *a user that the website trusts*". To be trusted a user must be authenticated. Can you please share a link where the attack on regular login/password form is described in details?