# MVC3 Anti Forgery - How to use Salt from Config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [runtime loading of ValidateAntiForgeryToken Salt value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994550/runtime-loading-of-validateantiforgerytoken-salt-value)

I have added the salt into config file but its throwing the following error. is there any way to use the Salf value from config file? I have tried to use `Static` instead of `const` but not working.

**Error**
`constant initializer must be compile-time constant`

**Code**

```
public const string SaltValue= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaltValue"]; 

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = SaltValue)]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel someViewModel)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a public static readonly SaltValue and then assign the value from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaltValue"] in the constructor for the controller.  It's two steps, one to create the string and one to populate the value in the constructor.  Then you should be able to use it in your ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.